# JavaScript - JSP - How correctly attach a function to a button in an existing form?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, google-app-engine, jsp, button

I'm writing several JSP pages and i need to attach a function to a button in an existing form. In this form, the submit button performs a navigation to another jsp view (I'm using MVC pattern with Slim3 framework, on Google AppEngine), and I need another button (next to submit button) to perform a navigation to another different JSP view. So, to achieve this, i create another button of "button" type in the existing form, create a .js file where I put my JavaScript code to perform "alternative" navigation and included the .js in the JSP view. But, it doesn't works ._. Here's the code:

JSP page containing the form:

```
...
<body>
    <%@ include file="script.js" %>
    <%@ include file="../header.jsp" %>
    <%@ include file="sidebar.jsp" %> 

    <div id="content">
        <div id="main">
            <p>Hello main admin testimonials edit Index !!!</p>
            <h2><b>Modifica Testimonial</b></h2>
            <form action="update" method="post">
                <h3>Nome: </h3>
                <textarea name="name">${f:h(testimonial.name)}</textarea><br />
                <h3>Cognome: </h3>
                <textarea name="surname">${f:h(testimonial.surname)}</textarea><br />
                <h3>Dettagli: </h3>
                <textarea name="details">${f:h(testimonial.details)}</textarea><br />
                <h3>Progetto:</h3>
                <select name="projectKey" selected="${f:h(testimonial.projectRef.key)}">
                    <c:forEach items="${projectsList}" var="project">
                        <option value="${f:h(project.key)}">${f:h(project.name)}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Aggiorna"/>
                <input type="button" value="Elimina" onclick="delete()"/>
                <input type="hidden" ${f:hidden("key")}/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        function delete()
        {
            if (confirm('Ask navigation confirm'))
            {
                window.navigate("bla bla new view url");
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
</script>
```

EDIT: I change the name of function, replacing with the real name in my original code.

Comment: *How* doesn't it work. What happens?

Comment: I click button and confirm dialog doesn't appear, nothing happens!

Comment: Does the page source contain your JavaScript code? Does the error console indicate any error? What happens if you use Firbug or Chrome developer tools to debug your JavaScript code?

Comment: The JavaScript code is located in the "script.js" file, if i understand Your question. It's my first JS code, how can i find the error console (I'm using Firefox) ? Same for the third question, it's first time I hear Firebug etc. xD

Comment: Right-click in the page and choose "SOurce code of the page" (or something like that, I use a French Firefox), to see if the generated HTML looks like what you want. Choose "Tools - Web developer - Error console" to get the error console. Install Firebug and see http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel for how to use the script panel.

Comment: Ok, <%@ include file="script.js" %> works well, putting the code in script.js in page. Now, it works rightly! I changed the function name, passing from "delete()" to "fdelete()", seems that "delete" name can create issues, I'm thinking that because I tried to write directly the JavaScript in the page (a really simple alert) and call it from button, with "delete()" function name the script didn't run! I can't understand why, but there it is.

Comment: Maybe the included sidebar.jap, or another included resource, redefines the same delete function to something else.

Comment: I don't think so, the other JSP pages are empty of JavaScript code!

Comment: Anyway, thank You for Your help and support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, <%@ include file="script.js" %> works well, putting the code in script.js in page. Now, it works rightly! I changed the function name, passing from "delete()" to "fdelete()", seems that "delete" name can create issues, I'm thinking that because I tried to write directly the JavaScript in the page (a really simple alert) and call it from button, with "delete()" function name the script didn't run! I can't understand why, but there it is.

EDIT: After many years of web development I stepped into this question again. *Of course* a function named "delete" can't work, because "delete" it's a JavaScript reserved word!

JavaScript God, please forgive my sins, I was young and inexperienced :(